# Ethernet connection not working on a specific machine

Tags: networking, ethernet

Im using Ubuntu 15.04, and after two days of searching, I can't fix my ethernet connection. The Network Manager keeps trying to connect, but it's permanently searching. Manually configuring it makes it seems like it's connected, but I still can't ping anything, not even my router. Here are the basic information:

lspci

```
03:00.0 Ethernet controller: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd. RTL8111/8168/8411 PCI Express Gigabit Ethernet Controller (rev 06)
```

lshw

```
                configuration: autonegotiation=on broadcast=yes driver=r8169 driverversion=2.3LK-NAPI duplex=full firmware=rtl8168e-3_0.0.4 03/27/12 latency=0 link=yes multicast=yes port=MII speed=100Mbit/s
```

ifconfig

```
eth0      Link encap:Ethernet  HWaddr fc:aa:14:2d:cb:aa  
      inet6 addr: fe80::feaa:14ff:fe2d:cbaa/64 Scope:Link
      UP BROADCAST RUNNING MULTICAST  MTU:1500  Metric:1
      RX packets:1662 errors:0 dropped:4 overruns:0 frame:0
      TX packets:69 errors:0 dropped:470 overruns:0 carrier:0
      collisions:0 txqueuelen:1000 
      RX bytes:108808 (108.8 KB)  TX bytes:6216 (6.2 KB)

lo        Link encap:Local Loopback  
      inet addr:127.0.0.1  Mask:255.0.0.0
      inet6 addr: ::1/128 Scope:Host
      UP LOOPBACK RUNNING  MTU:65536  Metric:1
      RX packets:2763 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
      TX packets:2763 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
      collisions:0 txqueuelen:0 
      RX bytes:229209 (229.2 KB)  TX bytes:229209 (229.2 KB)
```

I am doing a dual-boot, and it works on the other OS. The same cable has been used on another Ubuntu system, and it worked there. I'm out of ideas, any help will be appreciated

Comment: Try not using Network Manager and configuring the interfaces manually.

Comment: I tried doing so through /etc/network/interfaces, but it didn't work